# SSD/HDD RAID 1 Partitioning scheme

Tags: linux, partition

I've setup a small debian+postgresql+nginx server for a ERP application i've designed for my small business. I have two hard drives:

```
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk model: Samsung SSD 970 EVO 500GB

Device           Start      End  Sectors  Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1    2048  1050623  1048576  512M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2 1050624 42993663 41943040   20G Linux filesystem

Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD10EZEX-08W
```

Currently The application itself isn't that big. The database should be the only dynamic data. Since it's going to run on LAN, i only plan to keep error logs.
What would be the best partitioning scheme for this server? There's a lot of different suggestions online. My main questions are:

1. Do SSDs still require special treatment like described in [this 2013 article](https://wiki.debian.org/Multi%20HDD/SSD%20Partition%20Scheme)?
2. Which mount points require separate partitions?
3. Is RAID 1 a good idea for this setup? And if yes what is the best approach to setup RAID without losing data?

Comment: RAID1 doesn't make sense - you'd be throwing away the speed of the SSD and the capacity of your spinning disk

Comment: @roaima Seconded. For simplicity, I'd suggest expanding the Linux partition to fill the entire SSD. Use the mechanical disk for backups (yesterday, last week, last month). You retain the speed of the SSD and the HDD offers explicit redundancy. As the application grows, buy bigger devices. Then, maybe some time in the future, you switch to lvm to have the main partition span multiple devices.

Comment: Is there any benefit to creating separate partitions for home and database as some suggest?

Comment: For this scale? Almost certainly not